# Multiple Recordset/Columns echo to PHP from MSSQL stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a MSSQL stored procedure with PHP and then take results and echo them to a page. The results output as two different recordsets with a bunch of columns. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsZww.jpg).

I've modified some of the variable names and output to protect some sensitive information, but the SQL code below is exactly what I run in MSSQL Server Management Studio and it returns the output screenshot linked above.

I've also tried the following via PHP and it is returning no results:

```
if (!@mssql_connect($host,$username,$password)) {
    $error = $db_connect_error;
    echo $error;
}
@mssql_select_db($dbname);
$stmt=mssql_init("[dbo].[stored_procedure_name]");
mssql_bind($stmt, "@StartTime",    $start_last, SQLVARCHAR, FALSE);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@EndTime",  $end_last, SQLVARCHAR, FALSE);
mssql_bind...continued for all variables
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
$arr = mssql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($arr);
```

I've tried a couple of other different ways I've found via Googling to get the data to be echoed or saved to an array in PHP, but nothing I have tried has worked.

MSSQL statement that runs without issue in MSSQL Server Management Studio, this is the default format when I find the stored procedure and run it from MSSQL SMS:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime
DECLARE @a varchar(4000)
DECLARE @b varchar(4000)
DECLARE @c varchar(50)
DECLARE @d varchar(50)
DECLARE @e varchar(50)
DECLARE @f varchar(50)
DECLARE @g int
DECLARE @h int
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @j int
DECLARE @k int
DECLARE @l int
DECLARE @m int
DECLARE @n int
DECLARE @o int
DECLARE @p int
DECLARE @q int
DECLARE @r varchar(100)
DECLARE @s int
DECLARE @t float
DECLARE @u float
DECLARE @v float
DECLARE @w int

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

SET @StartTime = '2017-02-01 07:30'
SET @EndTime = '2017-02-01 19:30'
SET @a = 'string'
SET @b = 'string'
SET @c = 'string'
SET @d = 'string'
SET @e = 'string'
SET @f = 'string'
SET @g = 105
SET @h = 108
SET @i = 101
SET @j = 147
SET @k = 124
SET @l = 141
SET @m = 103
SET @n = 186
SET @o = 185
SET @p = 113
SET @q = 182
SET @r = 'string'
SET @s = 77
SET @t = 101.5
SET @u = 1000
SET @v = 25.4
SET @w = 1

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[spLocal_RptCvtgLinestatus] 
   @StartTime
  ,@EndTime
  ,@a
  ,@b
  ,@c
  ,@d
  ,@e
  ,@f
  ,@g
  ,@h
  ,@i
  ,@j
  ,@k
  ,@l
  ,@m
  ,@n
  ,@o
  ,@p
  ,@q
  ,@r
  ,@s
  ,@t
  ,@u
  ,@v
  ,@w
```

Comment: Where is your connection? Also, you should really consider updating to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't add the connection info, I've added it to the original post above the other PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First as my comment mentions you should think about updating to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

For your current set up you are missing the connection it looks like

```
$connection = mssql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
//Select a db
mssql_select_db('your_db_name', $connection);

//Use the connection. I do not think you need to fully qualify the sproc name.
$stmt = mssql_init('stored_procedure_name', $connection);
```

Also, when doing mssql_fetch_row it only returns one row so you will want to loop it:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Ahh that worked! Thank you! Yeah, I don't think updating is a viable option at this point for different reasons, but I wanted to add that in order to get around some NULL errors, I had to add:

    mssql_query('set ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON',$connection);

Answer (score 0):

To loop through multiple recordsets you can try this..

```
$sql = "EXEC spr_MyStoredProcedure @param1 = 6, @param2 = 5;";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $hostname, array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password ));
if( !$conn) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, null);
if($result ) {
    while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){ // check the first recordset
        print_r($obj);
    }
    while( sqlsrv_next_result($result)){ // if there are any more recordsets
        while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){ // loop them too
            print_r($obj);
        }   
    }
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result ); 
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

This hasn't been tested in a production environment yet so your mileage may vary.